# Can't disable Magento Extension at xml file

Tags: xml, magento

When I try to disable a custom magento extension I generally disable it by changing the active node at the extension module config to false.

But at my Development server this isn't working at all.

Cleaning cache by deleting all folders and files under /var/cache has no efect.

How to figure out what's the problem?

Comment: Have you refresh the configuration Cache ?? It's supposed to be the first in the manage cache page : Configuration  System(config.xml, local.xml) and modules configuration files(config.xml).  CONFIG

Comment: Yes i cleared the whole cache. Also by deleting all contents from /var/cache

Comment: The compilation is turned off or on ? Disable the compilation if it's ON.

Comment: Yeah. Compilation is still turned off due to this is a Development Server for pure development.

Comment: IT's very strange, if you turn off a module in the /app/etc/modules directory, with no cache and no compilation it should be working...